Can off-the-shelf "Ideal Diode" modules be used in Diode Or-ing circuit for power redundancy systems?
I'm designing a 12V UPS for my router and modem, and have come across common diode or-ing circuits such as this one:

(source: Static and Dynamic Behavior of the MAX40200 in a Diode ORing Application)
While this seems the simplest way to provide power redundancy, I have not yet seen anyone use off-the-shelf "ideal diode" modules that can be found on eBay or Aliexpress, such as this:

(source: 3-28V 15A High Current Ideal Diode on Aliexpress)
which I believe to be a product following this sort of design (though not exactly the same, as the Aliexpress one has 2 transistors, possibly for higher current):

(source: https://github.com/xioTechnologies/Ideal-Diode)
In theory this should provide the same protection/redundancy as a normal diode ORing circuit, with much less voltage drop. Is there any reason why this wouldn't work for diode ORing two separate power sources?

I wouldn't use an off-the-shelf module, personally, but I would use the same sort of circuit integrated onto my own custom PCB with all the other stuff needed for this sort of project. There are even dedicated ideal diode controller chips that can do fancier logic on their inputs than you get with just a handful of transistors.

Typically the documentation you get on these kinds of modules from eBay or Aliexpress is nearly useless, so it's at best a gamble, at worst a hazard.  As @Hearth said you're better off designing your own unless you can find something from a reputable manufacturer with proper documentation.  I suppose thorough enough reverse engineering of something this simple might be an option to gain confidence, but I wouldn't bother.

Thanks for the idea @Hearth I am making my own PCB anyway so I could well include a control IC (like LTC4412 that vir mentioned, or a similar one) and my own choice of MOSFET with heatsinking. I'll play around with circuits to see if I can integrate one in.

The schematic you show doesn't match the product; the schematic has two resistors and the photo shows two capacitors. The chip is in fact a LTC4412 which I imagine would have better performance than the transistor circuit as it actively adjusts Vgs to maintain ~20mV across the pass elements.
I would take a look at how much current you're trying to pass and do some back of the envelope calculations on heat produced and see if it makes sense with the area of the board and the thickness of the copper. I've certainly seen worse-looking modules - there aren't a whole lot of corners to cut here with the exception of counterfeit parts - and the 15A figure (if we're looking at the same module) seems reasonable-ish. I'd probably operate below 10A just to be safe and take some thermal measurements at current before putting a bow on it, however.

Thanks for the answer - I couldn't find the exact schematic for that one, so I found one that looked reasonably close, but I didn't notice that not all of the components were the same. I did see some ICs but they had the MOSFETs integrated in - and as such worked at far lower currents than I need (6A maximum but more like 4A on average). This sort of IC along with my own design looks like a good idea, seeing as I can use a chunky MOSFET and heatsinks to tailor it to my needs.
